# mypy: optional argument initialised to default value and used in lambda

Tags: mypy

I have a function of the form

```
def do_stuff(x: Optional[Dict[str, int]]=None)
    if x is None:
        x = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}

    # no type error
    for k in x.keys():
        a = x.get(k)

    # type error 
    sorted(x.keys(), lambda k: x.get(k))
```

This raises a type error

```
Item "None" of "Optional[Dict[str, int]]" has no attribute "get"
```

On the `sorted(x.keys()` line. I assume this is because mypy hasn't realised that I've defined `x` in the `if x is None:` line so that it's no longer optional. This *doesn't* raise an error in the `for k in x.keys():` .... `x.get(k)`  form, only when the `x.get(k)` is in `sorted` (or perhaps in a lambda).

Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: mypy will cast only from operations in the same scope - this doesn't count for lambdas anymore as they have their own scope. If you are not bound to use a lambda, first transform it to a local function `def comp(k: str) -> Optional[int]: return x.get(k)` - you should still get the same error. Fix it by adding `assert x is not None` before `return` line.